# Diferencia entre while(a != b) y while( !(a == b) )

Tags: operador, lenguaje-agnóstico

Me gustaría saber la diferencia entre estas dos expresiones:

- `while(a != b)`
- `while( !(a == b) )`

¿Cuál es la utilidad del operador `!`?

Comment: Específicamente, la diferencia va, por el tema de que te detecta la comparación, mientras que la primera te dice mientras la variable sea diferente de password, la segunda evalua que sea igual a password, luego cambia ese resultado por el contrario (si es true, entonces lo coloca como false, y viceversa).

Comment: Seguro no es `!=`?

Comment: Explicado brevemente: `!` es el operador negación, es decir, niega ("invierte") lo que sea que se encuentre a continuación de él. Si lo pones delante de un boolean que contiene `true`, será como comparar con `false`, si lo pones delante de un `=` será lo opuesto, es decir, "diferente de". Lo que estás haciendo ahí es basicamente eso. en el caso de variable!=password, estás diciendo que si `variable ES DIFERENTE DE password`, si lo pones al principio estás primero calculando el resultado de la comparación (true o false) y luego negándolo, es decir, si son diferentes (`false`) el if será `true`

Comment: ¿Que has investigado por tu cuenta?

Answer (score 3):

Es un negador.
Imagina el siguiente ejemplo.
Tienes una contraseña cuyo valor correcto es "123456", entonces necesitas saber si es correcta la que el usuario agregó. Tu puedes usar:

```
if(contrasena == "123456")
    System.out.println("Es correcto);
else
    System.out.println("No es correcto);
```

Hasta ahí todo es lo habitual. Si `contrasena = "123456"` significa que es correcto ¿cierto? Bueno, lo que hace el operador `!` es negar esa sentencia. Si yo tengo:

```
if(contrasena != "123456")
    System.out.println("No es correcto);
else
    System.out.println("Es correcto);
```

Sí `==` significa "Es igual que", entonces `!=` "No es igual que". Por lo que si `contrasena = "123456"` sigue siendo correcto.
Ahora, ¿qué hace `!` antes de la comparación? Como comenté, es un negador, entonces si yo tengo:

```
if(!(contrasena == "123456"))
    System.out.println("No es correcto);
else
    System.out.println("Es correcto);
```

En este caso, si `contrasena = "123456"` y yo entro a ese if, lo que imprimirá será "Es correcto" porque aunque la sentencia es cierta (`true`) al agregar `!` estare negando esa condicional. Imagina este ejemplo:

```
boolean verdad = true;
boolean a = verdad;
boolean b = !verdad;
```

Si imprimimos el valor de `a` y `b`, el resultado sera:

```
a = true;
b = false;
```

Porque al añadir `!` cambiamos (negamos) el valor de `verdad`, lo mismo aplica, si utilizas `false`, su valor pasara a ser `true`.

Answer (score 2):

### TL;DR

Los operadores `!=` y `!` son diferentes:

- `!=`: Valida si sus dos operandos son diferentes (izquierda y derecha).
- `!`: Niega una condición

---

### Operador `!=`

En una expresión del tipo `while(var1 != var2)`, significa que el bloque de código que le corresponde al ciclo `while` se va a ejecutar mientras **`var1` sea diferente a `var2`.** Esto debido a que el ciclo `while` se va a ejecutar mientras su condición sea verdadera, el resultado de esta evaluación `var1 != var2` va a ser verdadera, siempre cuando `var1` sea diferente a `var2`.

Este operador se puede leer como *"no igual"*. En algunos lenguajes de programación puede tener otra representación, ejemplo [OCaml](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ocaml) con `<>`.

### Operador `!`:

En una expresión del tipo `while(!(var1 == var2))`, significa que se va a ejecutar el bloque del código que le corresponde al ciclo, dependiendo del resultado de la negación de la condición `var1 == var2`.

- `!VERDADERO` equivale a `FALSO`
- `!FALSO` equivale a `VERDADERO`

A rasgos abstractos, si el resultado de una expresión se evalúa como verdadera, el resultado de su negación se va a evaluar como falsa, y viceversa. Por lo tanto el ciclo `while` que se puso como ejemplo se va a ejecutar solo si **`var1` es diferente a `var2`.** Debido a que el ciclo se ejecuta mientras la condición sea verdadera, y para obtener una evaluación de `FALSO` a raíz de una negación, lo que se niega debe de ser VERDADERO.

### Orden de procedencia

El orden de procedencia es muy importante, al definirse un orden de procedencia por medio de paréntesis. Con decir `(!var1) == var2`,se estaría evaluando si **la negación de `var1` es igual a `var2`,** esto es diferente a evaluar la negación de si **`var1` es igual a `var2`** (`!(var1 == var2)`). Sin embargo, se va  a seguir obteniendo el mismo resultado.

- `(!VERDADERO) == VERDADERO` equivale a `FALSO == VERDADERO`, que equivale a `FALSO`
- `!(VERDADERO == VERDADERO)` equivale a `!VERDADERO`, que equivale a `FAlSO`

`VERDADERO` y `FALSO` no necesariamente tienen que ser la representación booleana explicita que ofrezca el lenguaje de programación, muchos lenguajes de programación le dan valores booleanos a otro tipo de dato implícitamente. Lo más es común es que se consideren como `VERDADERO` los números mayores a 0, y como `FALSO` 0 junto con los números negativos.

### Conclusión

Ambas expresiones `while(var1 != var2)` y `while(!(var1 == var2))` son lo mismo, se puede decir que negar una igualdad es equivalente a una desigualdad.

Answer (score 0):

`!` es un operador de negación. Su función es invertir el valor de una variable o expresión booleana, por ejemplo:

```
boolean a = true;
a = !a; // ahora a es false
boolean b = !(true && true); // b es false
```

En tu pregunta, en el primer caso: `while(variable != password)` el ciclo se ejecutará siempre que el valor contenido en `variable` sea diferente a `password`.

En el segundo caso: `while( !(variable == password) )` si el valor de `variable` no es igual a `password` eso sería `false` y el ciclo no se ejecutaría, pero como se usa la negación `!` ese valor `false` se convierte en `true` y el ciclo se ejecuta.

Ambas instrucciones son equivalentes.